# Microsoft SQL server backup : restoring data to one table

Tags: sql-server, backup

Is there an easier way to restore data to single table in an MSSQL server, rather taking down the database and restoring the entire database?

Answer (score 2):

You can restore the database from the backup file to another database name on the same server, or different server, then copy the data over.

If the database was **Northwind**, something like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE NorthwindTemporary
FROM DISK="D:\Backups\NorthwindBackup.bak"
WITH MOVE 'Northwind_Log' TO 'D:\SQL\NorthwindTemporary.ldf',
     MOVE 'Northwind_Data' TO 'D:\SQL\NorthwindTemporary.mdf'
```

[StackOverflow: How do I restore a single table from a SQL Server 2005 backup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297422/how-do-i-restore-a-single-table-from-a-sql-server-2005-backup)

Answer (score 2):

There is a third party product, [LiteSpeed for SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/features-benefits.aspx), which offers this capability of object and even row-level recovery.

Comment: If your running SQL 2005 or earlier lightspeed will also compress your backups very nicely. its a great product

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server cannot do table-level backups or restores, although you can [backup and restore files within a database if you want to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477.aspx)

You're best bet is probably to restore the entire backup as a temporary database, and then copy the data you need over to the main database.

Tools like [RedGate's SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_data_compare/index.htm) are good for synchronising data.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to Generate Scripts from the first original database, and choose 1 table, and Script Data. Then execute this script on your database (where you wish to restore just 1 table).

If you don't have access to the original database, then restore the backup to a new database, create the Generate Scripts.. script from there, and then remove the new database.